# How to join two tables in pyspark that were obtained by two inline() and have no common column

Tags: json, pyspark

I am parsing a JSON file in pyspark. The file has "many branches". I put a figure of the branch I am interested in.
I get two dataframes:

```py
df1=df.select(F.expr("inline_outer(features.geometry)"))
df2=df.select(F.expr("inline_outer(features.properties"))
```

Each has 10 lines.  How could I join them to be sure that they are properly merged? They have no common column.
The JSON file has the structure

```
{features: [{"id":0, 
         "geometry":{"type" : "Polygon", "coordinates": "Polygon_1_coordinates"},
         "properties":{"area_id":101, "date": "2022-01-01", "amount":1002 }
        },
        {"id":2, 
         "geometry":{"type" : "Polygon", "coordinates": "Polygon_2_coordinates"},
         "properties":{"area_id":102, "date": "2022-06-05", "amount":33}
        },
        {"id":3, 
         "geometry":{"type" : "Polygon", "coordinates": "Polygon_3_coordinates"},
         "properties":{"area:id":103, "date": "2022-08-05", "amount":12}
        },
        {"id":4, 
         "geometry":{"type" : "Polygon", "coordinates": "Polygon_4_coordinates"},
         "properties":{"area:id":104, "date": "2021-06-05", "amount":7895}
        }]}
```

I need a table: with columns: "Area_ID", "Amount", "coordinates"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NRon.png

Comment: add your expected output..!